# pic18f why use LATx? Read modify write explanation

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I want to know how exactly do read modify write instructions on `PORTx` work and why do they cause problems. I used pic12f683 earlier and I don't remember having any issues while writing to `GPIO`. Why do some examples work while others don't?

```
//works
while(1) {
  LATA++;
  Delay_ms(1000);
}

//works
char i = 0;
while(1) {
  PORTA = i++;
  Delay_ms(1000);
}


//doesn't work
while(1) {
  PORTA++;
  Delay_ms(1000);
}

//doesn't work
char i = 0;
while(1) {
  i = PORTA;
  PORTA = i++;
  Delay_ms(1000);
}

//doesn't work either for some reason (PORTA seems to be read as 0 always)
char i = 0;
while(1) {
  i = PORTA;
  LATA = i++;
  Delay_ms(1000);
}

//neither does this one
char i = 0;
while(1) {
  i = LATA;
  LATA = i++;
  Delay_ms(1000);
}
```

Section 10 of pic18f4550 datasheet says:

> Reading the PORTA register reads the status of the pins; writing to it
>   will write to the port latch.

Doesn't it mean that writing to PORTA is the same as writing to LATA (port latch ...or is it)?
Here is the picture in case it helps with the explanation.

[image]

Comment: The last three examples all fail for the same reason: you write what was read, and discard the incremented value of `i`. IMO it is a bad idea to read from an output port: it is not an input port, and may not always be readable. You might also be upsetting some hardware status. Save a copy of what you wrote. If you need to modify the output, modify the copy and write that to the port. Some registers also have shared usage, with reading or writing using *different* hardware registers from the same address.

Comment: Not that this answers your question, but if you are going to use a port in this way, keep a local copy of the port (i) and then modify it (i++) then write it when you change it (PORTA=i; or LATA=i;), and dont bother reading.  I assume you were just using the whole port as a counter to understand and arent really using the port this way?

Comment: Perhaps you did not set ANSEL and by default RA0 is going to always read as 0. This will cause the behavior you are seeing and is a very nice example of the problem you are asking about. You can write to LATA what you want, what you read back will be 0.

Read-modify-write can now catch you if you have written a 1 to RA0, and you do something like PORTA |= 0x02; This will set one bit only (bit 2 in LATA register) or at least that is your intention, but the device will read the entire port, mask in the 2nd bit and write it back to the LATA register. Problem is it read 0 for RA0 so this breaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Reading the PORTA register reads the status of the pins; writing to it
>   will write to the port latch.

As stated above, it means that what you want to write will always be written in a LAT (latch register), but it doesn't mean that it will be the state of the port output. For example it is possible that you have wrong TRIS configuration (set port or IO pin as an input), or you have hardware malfunction which pulls pin low or high, etc. All this means that you can write to the port (LAT) but the result that you will read doesn't have to be the same as one you wrote.

Reading from the port will always return the current (physical) state of these lines no matter what is in LAT.